# Is it possible to find the first instance of a value from a Hashmap within the same loop?

Tags: java, hashmap

Ok so I have an interview coding problem, and the problem states that in one loop I must find the first instance of a non repeating character. So for example if the string was "abcab" it would return c since a and b repeat.

I have the following which iterates through the entire string, and inputs the amount of characters that occur into a hash map, and it works.

```
private static  boolean findFirstCharacter(String s) {
     HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

       for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
           char c = s.charAt(i);
            if(!map.containsKey(c)){
                map.put(c,1);

            }else{
               int value =  map.get(c);
               value++;
               map.put(c,value);


            }



        }


}
```

Now obviously I can just iterate again and find the first instance where the key has a value of 1, but It must be one loop. Is there anyway to do this given what I have or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: That's the way!

Comment: Why would a `findFirstCharacter` method return `boolean`? Shouldn't it return the character (or maybe the position)?

Comment: @Andreas you're right it should return a char, but I just wrote this method out now to present it as a method because originally it was just in the main class.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to do it in a single loop.

The method can handle Unicode characters from the supplementary planes, and has been modified to return the first non repeating character, instead of a `boolean`.

*Note: The code requires Java 8+.*

```
private static String findFirstCharacter(String s) {
    Set<Integer> singles = new LinkedHashSet<>(), duplicates = new HashSet<>();
    s.codePoints().forEach(ch -> {
        if (! duplicates.contains(ch) && ! singles.add(ch)) {
            singles.remove(ch);
            duplicates.add(ch);
        }
    });
    return (singles.isEmpty() ? null : new String(new int[] { singles.iterator().next() }, 0, 1));
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(findFirstCharacter("abcab"));
System.out.println(findFirstCharacter("abcbca"));
System.out.println(findFirstCharacter(""));
```

*Output*

```
c
null
```

Comment: Hahaha I do not understand this at all. I will definitely look into it though.

Comment: Nice thought to handle code points. Your code runs fine on Java 8 btw. You can simplify it a bit by using a set of unique characters and all characters instead of unique and duplicates (like in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51268304/2711488), but with codepoints instead of char values).

Comment: @Holger Can't run on Java 8, since [`codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) wasn't added until Java 9.

Comment: That’s not true, [`codePoints()` was added in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--). Might not be so obvious, as it has been inherited from `CharSequence` while in Java 9, the `String` class overrides it with a more efficient implementation. But it’s available in both versions.

Answer (score 4):

The key point is to use a `LinkedHashSet` to hold all unique characters, which remembers the insertion order, hence, allows to retrieve the first one:

```
// better method name would be findFirstUniqueCharacter
private static char findFirstCharacter(String s) {
    HashSet<Character> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(), seen = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(seen.add(c)) unique.add(c); else unique.remove(c);
    }
    return unique.isEmpty()? '_': unique.iterator().next();
}
```

`seen.add(c)` only adds the character if it is not contained in the `Set` and returns whether it has added it. It’s the often forgotten contract of all collections to return whether they have added the element, which together with the contract of `Set` makes additional `contains` checks obsolete.

So if `seen.add(c)` was successful, we add the character to the set of unique characters, otherwise, we remove it.

At the end of the loop, `unique` contains all remaining unique characters in the encounter order, so we can simply return its first element.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is that you need to filter out chracters with multiple occurence.

Your approach of counting the occurrences forces a second iteration over the map to filter the results.

<strike>Also you don't meet the requierment since you don't remember the actual index of the character.</strike>

I would do this with an extra collection like that (not tested):

```
 Collection<Character> seenCharacters = new HashSet<>();
 Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
 for(Character c : s.toCharArray()){
   if(seenCharacters.contains(c)){  // at least second occurrence
     map.remove(c); 
   } else {                         // first occurence
     seenCharacters.add(c);
     map.put(c,s.indexOf(c));
   }
 }
```

Of cause you have to do an aditional iteration over the result map for output (since `System.out.println(map);` is a *hidden* iteration).

---

> But how do you identify the first nonrepeating character without an additional loop? – Holger

Sorry, missed that part.

to get that we change `seenCharacters` from `Collection` and `HashSet` to `List` and `ArrayList`.

```
 List<Character> seenCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
```

After the loop we cheat:

```
 seenCharacters.retainAll(map.keySet()); // hidden iteration
 retun seenCharacters.isEmpty()?
            ' ':
            seenCharacters.get(0);
```

But wait, we are not required to output the position, so we do not need the `Map` which makes it much easier ...

```
 List<Character> seenCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Character> singleCharacters = new ArrayList<>();
 for(Character c : s.toCharArray()){
   if(seenCharacters.contains(c)){  // at least second occurrence
     singleCharacters.remove(c); 
   } else {                         // first occurence
     seenCharacters.add(c);
     singleCharacters.add(c);
   }
 }
 retun singleCharacters.isEmpty()?
            ' ':
            singleCharacters.get(0);
```

Comment: oh sorry I should've stated in the post it should return the character and if it doesn't exist (all characters repeat) then it returns the character '_'

Comment: You mixed up the `seenCharacters` and `singleCharacters` collections in your last code snippet (just compare with your first code snippet). Besides that, I wouldn’t use an `ArrayList` for repeated `contains` and `remove` operations.

Answer (score 0):

A possible and elegant solution could be done with this (required java 8)

```
private static  boolean findFirstCharacter(String s) {
    List<String> listChars = Arrays.asList(s.split(""));
    Map<String, Long> map = listChars.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));

    for(String key : map.keySet()) {
        if(map.get(key) == 1) {
            System.out.println("Result: " + key);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Since the type of the `Map` returned by `groupingBy` is unspecified, there is no guaranteed order, hence, this solution returns an arbitrary unique character, not the first one.